# Creating a scheduled task on Windows using C?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, windows-task-scheduler

I want to create a scheduled task on Windows using C. I reseached this topic and found the [task scheduler interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/task-scheduler-2-0-interfaces) provided by Microsoft. I was able to successfully create scheduled tasks using C++. However, due to limitations I can only use C for this and it seems that the interfaces are only provided for C++. I tried researching this but couldn't find any results. Is it possible to create scheduled tasks in Windows using C?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do COM in C but it is far uglier than with C++.

For example, if you look in mstask.h you will find macros like ITask_CreateTrigger following the definition of ITask. You can use those macros instead of C++ style member calls. With headers created from IDL it is generally a fairly mechanical task to transform C++ style COM code to C. If the interface is not generated from IDL then the C macros may well not be present but that is not an issue for the task scheduler API.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you maybe have a small practical example on how I could approach this?

Comment: After thinking about it I guess it's faster to just use ShellExecute to create the task with cmd instead. Not sure if it's a reliable solution though...and I'm a bit scared of false detection by antivirus vendors.